# Discord.py Reaction Roles with Embed dont work

Tags: discord.py

Im Trying to make a discord bot which sends an embed message with a reaction, and if a user reacts to that message he/she would get a role. This is for the Rules of the Server.

The Problem is, the Embed message gets sent but there is no reaction. If I manually react to it, and get someone else to react too he/she will get no role. (The embed message is the only message in that channel). I also get no Errors in the console.

The 'channel_id_will_be_here' is always replaced with the correct channel Id.

Thank you.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel('channel_id_will_be_here')
    print("Ready as always chief")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find("|rules12345654323") != -1:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="**Rules**", description="The Rules Everybody needs to follow.", colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(236, 62, 17))
        embedVar.add_field(name="Rule 1", value="Be nice etc", inline=False)
       
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('channel_id_will_be_here')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == ":white_check_mark:":
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Player")
        await client.add_roles(user, Role)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel` you compare the id to the Channel object,  not the Channel.id.

You don't need to use the object there, just the id (which you use to create the channel object in the first place) would be fine

```
if reaction.message.channel.id != channel_id_will_be_here:
    return
```

You could also use the message id like(So it'll only trigger when reacting to that exact message):

```
if reaction.message.id != rules_message_id_will_be_here:
    return
```

The way you do your check is pretty strange too, why check to make the function return if False? Why not just make it add the role when True?

```
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.channel.id == channel_id_will_be_here and reaction.emoji == ":white_check_mark:":
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Player")
        await client.add_roles(user, Role)
```

You could even leave out the `if reaction.emoji == ":white_check_mark:":` part if it is the only message/emote reaction in that channel

Comment: Thank you, I think that should work. I thinks its on my side but I tried to use the code you provided (obviously changing the 'id_here's with the correct Id's) but still nothing, I tried to replace the name with the Role id, but still nothing. I noticed that the "add_roles" part is highlighted and is "Unresolved attribute reference 'add_roles' for class 'Client'". Thats definitely something I did wrong. But Im not sure what.

Comment: I wasnt quite sure about that client.add_roles either but i assumed it was something i didnt know about so i kept it. You probably want user.add_roles instead of client.add_roles https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles (which should work)

Comment: I have read that before and yet it doesnt work, its like that entire code part does not exist. It doesnt say its not reachable or anything. Just doesnt do anything. I tried to change up the code a bit, I moved the role to the lowest possible place. Well, anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: If it was giving nothing there probably is an issue with the if statement, try printing out reaction.message.channel.id and reaction.emoji before the if statement, see what it returns and debug from there

Comment: Ah yes, it works now. Yeah the if statement was the issue. Thank you so much.